# Error: No method named "destroy" for popover bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I want to close popover automatically after a delay time. but its showing an error [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9XmQ.png)

```
$('#prev_button').popover('show');

$('#prev_button').on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
  var $pop = $(this);

  setTimeout(function() {
    $pop.popover('destroy');
  }, 1000);
});
```

bootstrap.bundle.js is included to ensure popover method works. Can't figure out a solution

PS: using v4.1 bootstrap

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As of version 4.1, the method `destroy` has been replaced by `dispose`. You can find more details [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/popovers/#popoverdispose).

```
$pop.popover('dispose');
```

Answer (score 1):

Please share bootstrap version details for better help & it would be better if you could prepare a jsfiddle.
Here is a jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/iamaditya/gv1j4pa7/6/) where you can find your code working with Bootstrap 3.0.
If you are using Bootstrap 4 following [reference](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/) would help.
Some suggestions:
1. If you just intend to close it you should use [hide](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#popover-hide) rather than [destroy](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#popover-destroy).
2. You can also directly pass [delay](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#popovers-options) as an option to delay show or hide such that

```
delay: { 
   show: "500", 
   hide: "1000"
},
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

The Popover plugin is similar to tooltips. To destroy the shown popover you can use the following code-snippet:

```
$pop.popover('destroy'); // jQuery < 4.1
$pop.popover('dispose'); // jQuery > 4.1
```

You can also remove all created popovers from your DOM via `.popover` class (each popover has an id, so by knowing the IDs you can be more precise)

```
$('.popover').remove();
```